# File with div.gz extension (mistake?)

Tags: gzip

I tried downloading a zipped folder from Arxiv (https://arxiv.org/format/math/0606086 under DVI)

but it downloads as div.gz. I understand that this is the TeX output. I tried TeX and various unzip apps, but none of them worked. I even tried renaming it just in case there was a mistake. Any suggestions? If this is not the right place, feel free to delete this.

Comment: Check the result of `file div.gz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file` command can be used to identify file format based on the contents of the file.

I clicked the "download DVI" button in Firefox and got a file named `0606086` with no extension.

```
$ file 0606086
0606086: TeX DVI file (TeX output 2021.09.21:0203\213)
```

I then ran `dvipdf` on it and got a readable PDF document as a result:

```
$ dvipdf 0606086
$ ls -l 0606086*
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  81088 Sep 21 07:31 0606086
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 177281 Sep 21 07:32 0606086.pdf
```

The `okular` viewer on my KDE desktop environment could also display the file directly, without explicitly converting it to PDF.

The download URL reported by Firefox was `https://arxiv.org/dvi/math/0606086?` so I decided to take a look at the HTTP headers reported by the site:

```
$ curl --head https://arxiv.org/dvi/math/0606086?
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Sep 2021 04:39:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Set-Cookie: browser=89.27.98.38.1632199174381535; path=/; max-age=946080000; domain=.arxiv.org
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Sep 2021 02:03:27 GMT
ETag: "16c691a8-5cb5-5cc77cdb51712"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 23733
Content-Type: application/x-dvi
Content-Encoding: x-gzip
```

`Content-Type: application/x-dvi` matches the actual content, and `Content-Encoding: x-gzip` indicates the document is delivered compressed with `gzip`. Looks like my Firefox decompressed it automatically for me, perhaps because I had `gunzip` available, or perhaps Firefox has built-in support for this compression?